# How to receive raw data in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have jsp page that pass a xml string parameter to template in xsl.

My code in jsp like this:

```
<x:transform doc="${transactions}" xslt="${xslTransaction}">
    <x:param name="xmlCategory" value="${xmlCategory}"/>
</x:transform>
```

But when I print the value of `xmlCategory`and view page source. It gives me like this:

```
&lt;categories&gt;&lt;category&gt;&lt;id&gt;1&lt;/id&gt;&lt;type&gt;true&lt;/type&gt;&lt;name&gt;Salary&lt;/name&gt;&lt;userId&gt;1&lt;/userId&gt;&lt;/category&gt;&lt;/categories&gt;
```

Instead of:

```
<categories><category><id>1</id><type>true</type><name>Salary</name><userId>1</userId></category></categories>
```

I think because of that, I can not convert `xmlCategory` to node-set to iterate.

Can anybody explain to me this case and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible in the context of your setup, but you can try using `disable-output-escaping="yes"` in the XSLT.

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="..." />
```

This should prevent characters in selected strings from being escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that your server is escaping the XML special characters.
I suggest looking into decoding them back into the actual UTF-8 characters using something like the Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) or writing your own code that takes the escaped characters and replaces them appropriately (Like "&lt" to "<")